# Problema com envio de posts via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou criando um chat com `websocket`, quando envio uma mensagem ele salva a mensagem no banco. Esse é o exemplo de como ele envia o post da mensagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o problema está quando envio uma função `javascript` (estou tentando eliminar `javascript injection` no `input da mensagem`). Segue o print de como está enviando (Todo bugado) e só salva o início da mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia resolver este problema pra mim? 
Segue o código no Jsfiddle de como estou fazendo:
http://jsfiddle.net/otww9e2k/ (vejam as requisições enviadas via `XHR` para verem o post sendo bugado).

Comment: Dá uma olhada a ver se isto ajuda: http://jsfiddle.net/hympsp8f/

Comment: Não deu certo @Sergio

Comment: Qual é o erro que tens usando o  meu código? no devtools não vejo erro nenhum...

Comment: Você sabe que ali na sua imagem se você clicar no `view source` ele exibe exatamente o que você enviou né?

Comment: Sergio , vc deve olhar o XHR, pra vc ver o post dando o mesmo bug :/

Comment: @Ricardo e após o usuário selecionar como pode ser enviado esses dados selecionado para o mysql . Fica o meu caso tem como vê http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181981/form-din%C3%A2mico-e-envio-para-o-mysql-via-jquery-e-ajax?noredirect=1#comment376494_181981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) em javascript:

```
data: 'acao=' + encodeURIComponent(input),
```

Quando receberes a data no servidor deves fazer un decode em PHP:

```
urldecode()
```